# Redirect content to file and print content at same time?

Tags: io-redirection

I'm wondering if there is a way to redirect lines to a file and print that redirected lines at the same time?

Currently I do something like this:

```
echo "123:456" > output.txt ; awk 'BEGIN{...} {print ...}' output.txt > output2.txt
```

Do i really have to read output.txt **again** using awk or is there another way to access the lines i redirected to output.txt without reading them from my disk in order to process them going further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems what you want is `tee`, but more like:

```
echo "123:456"  | tee output.txt | awk 'BEGIN{...} {print ...}' > output2.txt
```

`tee` will write the input to `output.txt` and again to output, which is the pipe to awk.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using `tee`:

```
echo "123:456" > output.txt ; awk '<etc.>' output.txt | tee output2.txt
```